# Odd tag name in "How do I format my posts using Markdown or HTML?" help center page

Tags: discussion, tags, help-center

I was reading "[How do I format my posts using Markdown or HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)" and saw a section on tags. It said:

> To talk about a tag on this site, [like-this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/like-this), use
>
> ```
> See the many questions tagged [tag:elephants] to learn more.
> ```
>
> The tag will automatically be linked to the corresponding tag info page."

Why did they choose "elephant"?

As far as I know, that is not even a tag, and there is nothing on any websites related to Stack Overflow that talk about elephants.

I know it isn't a big deal, but it just seems off.

Comment: That brings me back. A while back I was writing some tests which checked if the security setup was correct, testing response codes from URLs and such. So I added tests where a non-existent user was used, and named that user "FLAARP". Because that user is definitely not going to exist. I got a review comment. "What is FLAARP?". Although I did do a facepalm because you really have to be reviewing without understanding what is going on, still lesson learned: don't use random garbage names. I changed it to "DefinitelyWrongUserName".

Comment: Do you have the slightest idea how offensive "flaarp" is in Common Katari? Consider yourself lucky you didn't get cancelled.

Comment: @user4581301 oof, didn't think about that. Even more reason not to use random names.  You just get yourself into trouble that way. Always stay on topic.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It is an illustrative example. It is supposed to illustrate.

Arguably, linking to an existing tag would be more distracting to the purpose of the example.

Comment: Not convinced: "_Arguably, linking to an existing tag would be more distracting to the purpose of the example._" I also remember finding this Section on that Help-Page completely confusing and finding the example on the contrary completely _distracting_, rather than using a _real_ high-volume Tag like `js`/`php`/`perl`/whatever... // For Syntax Highliting, they do use `\```lang-js` as example and not stg like `\```lang-elephant-squeak`...!?

Comment: There aren't syntax highlighting rules for the language elephant squeak. Thus there would not be a very useful illustrative example. As it won't illustrate anything.

Comment: Yep, that's the point, `like-this` and `elephants` are also _fake_ Tags...

Comment: But `[tag:elephants]` does illustrate what how the tag formatting works regardless whether or not the tag exists.

Comment: I do note that these help-pages are the same across all sites, even Stack Apps has elephants: https://stackapps.com/help/formatting. Moderators can't edit these pages, so we can't replace them with an existing tag. On the other hand: Why wouldn't we just create the tag? There are [enough elephants in the room](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=elephants) ...

Comment: "_But [tag:elephants] does illustrate what how the tag formatting works regardless..._": Beh no, that was the reason I reacted to your Answer, an example in some Help-Section calling more questions than explaining stg is not a very good example... I had understood it (2 or 3 years ago) only because I already had 20-30 Answers on 'SO' (and struggled often enough with Formatting), I can now 3 years later completely understand that some fairly new User could find that Section rather confusing and buggy... (But that was my mini-Feedback, I was not looking for a complete 'Discussion'...)

Comment: https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/babar-the-elephant